# Tabla en php segun valor enviado de formulario

Tags: php, array, tablas, sesiones

a ver si alguien me puede echar un cable con este problemilla.
Estoy creando una tabla de reservas a traves de los datos enviados por un formulario en la misma pagina.
Se trata de poner el nombre de la persona que reserva en el dia y la hora correcta.
Consigo hacerlo, el problema que tengo es que mi tabla va creando td's y me va moviendo los resultados obtenidos hacia la derecha, he probado de printar la tabla de otra manera pero me da diferentes errores segun lo que voy probando.

les dejo el codigo de impresion de la tabla, si necesitan mas codigo les paso les paso toda la hoja. muchas gracias de antemano!

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Tasca DWES2 - Gimnàs</h1>
        <div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <form name="canviPantalla" value="reservar" method="GET" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                        <button type="submit" name="canviPantalla" value="reservar" class="btn btn-primary">Reservar pista</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <form name="canviPantalla" value="reserves" method="GET" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                        <button type="submit" name="canviPantalla" value="reserves" class="btn btn-light">Veure Reserves </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <form name="reserva" method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                    <h2> Reserva pista</h2>
                    <p>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
                        <label for="dia">Dia:</label>
                        <select class="form-select" id="dia" name="dia">
                            <option value="1">Dilluns</option>
                            <option value="2">Dimarts</option>
                            <option value="3">Dimecres</option>
                            <option value="4">Dijous</option>
                            <option value="5">Divendres</option>
                        </select>
                        <label for="hora">Hora:</label>
                        <input type="number" step="1" max="20" min="15" name="hora" id="hora" required>
                    </p>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipopista" id="tipopista1" value="exterior">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="tipopista1">Exterior</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipopista" id="tipopista2" value="coberta">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="tipopista2">Coberta</label>
                    </div>
                    <h2> Usuari</h2>
                    <p>
                        <label for="nom">Nom i llinatges</label>
                        <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="telefon">Telefon</label>
                        <input type="number" name="telefon" id="telefon">
                    </p>
                    <div style="text-align: center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar" style="margin-right: 5px; width: 60px; height:30px; font-weight: bold">
                        <input type="reset" value="Limpiar" style="width: 60px; height:30px; font-weight: bold">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
//iniciamos sesion
session_start();


//comprobamos si se han rellenado todos los campos
if(empty($_REQUEST["nom"]) or empty($_REQUEST["telefon"]) or empty($_REQUEST["dia"]) or empty($_REQUEST["hora"]) or empty($_REQUEST["tipopista"])) {
    echo "faltan datos por poner";
}else{

    // creamos variables
    $nom=$_POST["nom"];
    $telefon=$_POST["telefon"];
    $dia=$_POST["dia"];
    $hora=$_POST["hora"];
    $tipopista=$_POST["tipopista"];
    
    
    // creamos contenido del array
    $Contenido = array("Nombre" => $nom, "Telefono" => $telefon, "Dia" => $dia, "hora" => $hora, "tipopista" => $tipopista); 
    
    
    // Cargamos el contenido en la session
    $_SESSION["reserva"][ ] = $Contenido;
     
    
    //creamos una variable de la session
    $array = $_SESSION["reserva"];
    
    //imprimimos resultados
    foreach($array as $nombre => $dades ) {
        if(($dades['Dia']=="1") && ($dades['hora']=="15")){
            echo "Todos los numeros son iguales";
            echo '<br>Dia: '.$dades['Nombre'].'<br>Hora: '.(int)$dades['hora'];
        }
    }
    
}

//imprimimos resultados sin formato
//print_r ($array);

echo 'numero de entradas son : '.sizeof($array).' en reservas';

//creacion datos para cabeceras de la tabla
$titolsCol=['','1','2','3','4','5'];
$titolsFilera=['15','16','17','18','19','20'];

//Cabecera
echo '<table class="table"><thead><tr>';

for($a=0;$a<count($titolsCol);$a++){
    echo '<th scope="col">'.$titolsCol[$a].'</th>';
}

echo '</tr></thead>';

//body de la tabla
echo '<tbody>';

//primer bucle
for($fila=0;$fila<count($titolsFilera);$fila++){
    echo '<tr><th scope="row">'.$titolsFilera[$fila].':00</th>';
    
    // segundo bucle
    for($col=0;$col<count($titolsCol)-1;$col++){

        foreach($array as $datosT){
    
            if(($datosT['Dia']==$titolsCol[$col+1]) && ($datosT['hora']==$titolsFilera[$fila])){
                echo '<td>'.$datosT["Nombre"].$titolsCol[$col+1].'</td>';
            }else {
                echo'<td></td>';
            //cerramos else de if            
            }
        //cerramos foreach
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
 //cerramos primer for fila
}
echo '</tbody></table>';

//session_destroy();

?>
```

Comment: Hola. La pregunta no es clara y el código es incompleto. ¿Cuál es el contenido de `$array`?

Comment: con que codigo agregas a la tabla??

Comment: Primero de todo gracias por vuestra pronta respuesta. Ahora editaré la pregunta con el codigo completo. Intentaré ser mas concreto. Desde un formulario, cargo datos en un array que a la vez se guarda en una sesion llamada Reservas[ ] para que me cree un indice por cada vez que envio el formulario.  Luego creo una tabla dinamica en php con bucles y condiciones para que me imprima el nombre en la casilla que coincida con el dia y la hora. La tabla se crea correctamente y el primer array se carga en la celda correspondiente, pero la segunda, si es en la misma hora me crea otro td hacia la derecha

Comment: He actualizado el codigo anterior por todo el codigo de la pagina, la parte de html en mi caso la tengo con include, pero para que les sea mas comodo lo he pegado al principio del documento. GRACIAS!

Comment: Si poneis bordes en la tabla vereis que en cuanto se envia el resultado automaticamente crea otro <td>  y asi sucesivamente, entonces se que el problema me viene del bucle pero no consigo encontrar el fallo por mucho que lo lea, que se les ocurre?

Comment: ***Desde un formulario, cargo datos*** puede ser mas preciso cargas datos adonde a un JavaScript o a php como pasas los datos de html a php???

Comment: esto: `$_SESSION["reserva"][ ] = $Contenido;` no lo guarda en reserva, en realidad queda guardado en `$_SESSION["reserva"][#]` que es un sub-array donde `#`  representa un numero; después de esa linea puedes colocar un `var_dump($_SESSION);` y validar que datos tienes capturados en la sesion.

Comment: tu código no esta indentado es difícil de entender, y la etiqueta head no tiene cierre `</head>`,  si quieres un comportamiento aceptable de tu sitio web debes asegurarte de que todo este completo; cierre y apertura de tags. valida que todo este bien y actualiza el código.

Comment: por que usas `$_REQUEST["nom"]` si tu formulario dice `POST`, no deberías de usar `$_POST` ???

Comment: no entiendo por que ejecutas el `PHP` al final del archivo... y usas `echo` para mostrar el armado de la tabla.... cuando esto ocurre tu `html` ya se ha mostrado y tiene todo las etiquetas de cierre estaría intentando mostrar datos en después del cierre `</html>`

Answer (score 0):

Ya esta, lo siento por la estructura del codigo, se que se hace algo complicado.
Todo lo que se es prueba error y busqueda en internet.

Bueno como suponia el error estaba en los buscles, se repetia el echo td /td tantas veces como registros hubiera.

este seria el resultado del printado de la tabla.

```
 //primer bucle
  for($fila=0;$fila<count($titolsFilera);$fila++){ //se repite 6 veces por default
    echo '<tr><th scope="row">'.$titolsFilera[$fila].':00</th>';
           
    // segundo bucle

            for($col=0;$col<count($titolsCol)-1;$col++){ //se repite 5 veces por default
             echo '<td style="border:solid">'.$col;
        foreach($array as $datosT) {
        
            if(($datosT['Dia']==$titolsCol[$col+1]) && ($datosT['hora']==$titolsFilera[$fila]))
            {
  
           echo $datosT["Nombre"].$titolsCol[$col+1];
            }
            }
       echo '</td>';
            

            //cerramos else de if             
             }
            //cerramos foreach
             }
             
                
             echo '</tr>';
            
  
 echo '</tbody></table>';
  
 
 //session_destroy();
```

Gracias igualmente, si a alguien le apetece, estaré muy agradecido si me "ordenan o limpian" el código para ver hasta donde podría haberlo reducido y así seguir aprendiendo.

Comment: tienes otros errores ... que pueden provocar un mal funcionamiento ...